# How to configure two custom login forms in a single <http> in spring security

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-security

**I want to provide two logins for jobseeker,one is popup login on index.jsp,and another is login page.I configured login page as follows.How to configure popup login for the jobseeker in security.xml** .

```
<http pattern="/jobseeker/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
            authentication-manager-ref="jobseeeker">
            <headers>
                <content-type-options disabled="true"/>
                <cache-control />
            </headers>
            <intercept-url pattern="/jobseeker/authentication/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/jobseeker/registration/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/jobseeker/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_JOBSEEKER')" />
            <form-login login-page="/jobseeker/authentication/jslogin/null"
                default-target-url="/jobseeker/dashboard/jshome"
                login-processing-url="/jobseeker/login_process"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                username-parameter="emailId" password-parameter="password" />

            <logout logout-url="/jobseeker/authentication/jslogout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
            <csrf />
            <remember-me user-service-ref="jobSeekerAuthenticationService"
               remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
               remember-me-cookie="remember-me"
                key="seckey"
               token-validity-seconds="86400"/>
        </http>
```

The popup login is ajax based login.The method returning the index.jsp url is **contexturl/**.How can I configure that? can anyone guide me to move further.Thanks